# Ggplot2 and tibble plotting geom_point not not detecting dates/factors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am stuck with this weird behaviour, I perhaps am not noticing something obvious. After data wrangling I ended up with a data set in long format, much like the one in socviz book:

[image]

But upon attempting to generate bars or geom_points, ggplot is not recognizing the years as separate factors. Please consider this MWE:

```
dep <- function(x) {
  if(!all(x %in% installed.packages()))
    install.packages(x[x %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"] == F])
  lapply(x, require, character.only = T)
}
dep(c("dplyr", "tibble", "ggplot2"))

a<-tribble(
  ~region,  ~icd_group1,                                              ~year, ~visits,
  "Midwest", "F00-F09 Organic, Including Symptomatic, Mental Dis.",     2008,  2.59,
  "Midwest", "F10-F19 Mental And Behav. Dis. Due To Substance Use" ,    2008,  3.18, 
  "South", "F20-F29 Schizophrenia, Schizotypal And Delusional Dis.",  2009, 13.1,  
  "Southeast", "F30-F39 Mood [Affective] Dis.",                           2009, 26.7,  
  "Southeast", "F40-F48 Neurotic, Stress Related And Somatoform Dis.",    2010,  7.77, 
  "North", "F50-F59 Behav. Synd. Assoc. w/ Physical Factors",         2010,  0.409
)
ggplot(a) + geom_point(size = 3)+ aes(x = "year", y ="visits", color = icd_group1)
```

But I am getting this:

[image]

I expected the three years along x axis.

- What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not put column names between quotes, they become the character vectors `"year"` and `"visits"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(tidyverse)
a %>% ggplot(aes(year, visits))+ geom_point(aes(color=icd_group1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this works. Its better to convert year to factor before, but works. Now, why?

Comment: You have to put the `aes()` function into the `ggplot()` function

Comment: @TobKel No, you are not. `aes()` can be added to `ggplot()` through `+`. Problem was in name quotation.

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin You don't *have to* but it's a standard practice.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Yes no arguing with that, but it's not a source of the error.

Comment: @AndreyKolyadin Yes you're right. You shouldn't put the variables in quotation marks.